# How to send data from parent to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I have a problem. Earlier I was having a hard time sending a `postMessage` from the iframe to the parent node. Fortunately, I solved it because somehow `window.parent.postMessage` didn't work but top.postMessage did work. Now I'm having the opposite problem. I want to postMessage from the parent to the iframe doing `myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage` but it doesn't work. Is there something else I could try?

I'm testing in localhost, one is at localhost:3000 and the other at localhost:9001

Comment: URL is not a concern. Please show more codes, and you can try to look into the browser console to see if there is any error.

Comment: read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
const iframeElement = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
// Do something with `iframeElement`
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp